# javascript can not reload the page checkoutform

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

after I clicked the "submit order" / btn_cod button, the page just silent no response at all! but when I click the home or any other pages is reloaded!

```
function CodSubmitOrder(){ $('#btn_cod').attr('disabled', true).addClass('disabled');

$.post('<?php echo base_url('/cod/process-payment');?>', function(data)
{
    if(data.errors != undefined)
    {
        console.log('data error');

        var error = '<div class="alert alert-danger">';
        $.each(data.errors, function(index, value)
        {
            error += '<p>'+value+'</p>';
        });
        error += '</div>';

        $.gumboTray(error);
        $('#btn_cod').attr('disabled', false).addClass('disabled');
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('data success');

        if(data.orderId != undefined)
        {
            window.location = '<?php echo site_url('order-complete/');?>/'+data.orderId;
        }
    }

    console.log(data);
}, 'json');}
```

Comment: try debugging what is causing issue,, for example there might be possibility of issue in php code, or any javascript statement issue in your other code...

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you use PHP `echo` is in cause.

I suppose that `$base_url` and `$site_url` are defined in PHP and are used many places... Something like this:

```
<?php
$base_url = "/cod/process-payment";
$site_url = "order-complete/";
?>
```

Check these, especially regarding the slashes...

Then, to echo them within your jQuery code, here is the way:

```
function CodSubmitOrder(){

    $('#btn_cod').attr('disabled', true).addClass('disabled');

    $.post('<?php echo $base_url; ?>', function(data){
        if(data.errors != undefined)
        {
            console.log('data error');

            var error = '<div class="alert alert-danger">';
            $.each(data.errors, function(index, value)
            {
                error += '<p>'+value+'</p>';
            });
            error += '</div>';

            $.gumboTray(error);
            $('#btn_cod').attr('disabled', false).addClass('disabled');
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('data success');

            if(data.orderId != undefined)
            {
                window.location = '<?php echo $site_url; ?>'+data.orderId;
            }
        }

        console.log(data);
    }, 'json');
}
```